# How can I force my computer to use my AMD GPU instead of the integrated Intel Card?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, windows-7

I just reinstalled Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520 and I'm trying to get the dicrete GPU selected. But even though I got the High Performance option selected on Catalyst Control Center, I can't get Skyrim to run on the discrete GPU. How can I get it working?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention this is a hybrid GPU, it needs the on chip intel one to perform in any level... IMHO, a crappy design.

Comment: Do both cards show up in launcher options?

Comment: No, only the Intel HD 4000.

Comment: Do you have a monitor connected to the on board GPU?  If not, completely disable it in bios.

Comment: Note that some switchable graphics systems will tell you they're running on the onboard card even though they're not - this is for architectural reasons.  This is not to say you might not be having a problem, of course - performance should be pretty obviously different.

Answer (score 1):

No guarantee to work (don't have a onboard card to test), but I'd assume the following should work:

- Go to `[my documents]\My Games\Skyrim` and open `SkyrimPrefs.ini` with your favorite text editor.
- Look for a line starting with `iAdapter=`. Actually it should state `iAdapter=0`. Change it to `iAdapter=1`.

Try launching the game again, avoid going into the launcher's settings.

Answer (score 1):

insall GPU-Z run the program and select the graphic-card you want to use. you can set the program to open when windows starts up. In that way you dont have to manually open it everytime you wont to play.

Comment: if you have nvidia control panel you can use that aswell. Simple find the program and select the right card.

Comment: I don't think nvidia control panel works on amd hardware. Or does it?

Comment: no idea, but you re properly right :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame your onboard gpu it comes in handy if you're on the road and don't want to waste a lot of power.

But concerning your question: Start your Skyrim launcher and then there should be the bullet point 'Options' which leads you to the graphics settings.
The first dropdown list there should be 'Graphics Adapter' if this isn't the case, try this [link to a dell forum thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19474269/20221062.aspx#20221062) about a similar problem with a Inspiron 14Z.

*add*:
Also one tip from there was to ensure you don't have a old GPU that lacks the power so try to uninstall your Radeon Driver and start the game. If the performance is even worse you know what to do. Use [fraps](http://fraps.com) and determine the frames per second to see the performance drop and if there is one.

Comment: Please add the details from the link into your answer.  Saves people a click, and ensures your answer can stand on it's own if the link ever goes down.

Comment: There are a lot of steps and pictures of which I'm sure I'm not allowed to copy, also I doubt that dell is going out of business any time soon plus. One tip from there was to ensure you don't have a old GPU that lacks the power so try to uninstall your Radeon Driver and start the game. If the performance is even worse you know what to do.

Comment: Our policy tends to frown on answers that rely on links. If your answer can't stand on it's own without the link, then you need to explain where it goes, and what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Catalyst Control Center->Power->PowerPla*y and make sure it's ***enabled***. Then go to *Graphics Switching* and assign *High Performance* to the `game.exe` file. Done.

[image: How can I force my computer to use my AMD GPU]